# Table inside a table HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I am have my HTML that have a table inside odd two

I want this

[image: table that I want]

but I have this

[image: table that i get]

How can I do the table td with the same ?

This is my code in HTML:

```
<table>
      <thead class='thead-dark'>
        <tr>
          <th>Semestre</th>
          <th>Curso</th>
          <th>Seccion</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for item in results%}

        <tr>
          <td>{{item.year}}</td>
          <td><table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            {% if item.A!= ""%}
              <tr><td><p>A.1</p></td></tr>
            {%endif%}
            {% if item.B != ""%}
            <tr><td><p>B.1</p></td></tr>
            {%endif%}
         </tr></table></td>
          <td><table>
            {% if item.A != ""%}
              <tr><td><p>{{item.A|linebreaks}}</p></td></tr>
            {%endif%}
            {% if item.B != ""%}
            <tr><td><p>{{item.B|linebreaks}}</p></td></tr>
            {%endif%}
            </tr></table></td>
          </tr>

      </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Comment: doesn't work.When I add rowspan in the <td> tag, it make B, puts next to A

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to nest a second table in it. Using "rowspan" as @Brian Tomspett suggested will do the trick.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item1</td>
      <td>Item2</td>
      <td>Item3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">A</td>
      <td rowspan="2">A.1</td>
      <td>A.1.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A.1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">A.2</td>
      <td>A.2.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A.2.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">A.2</td>
      <td>A.3.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A.3.2</td>
    </tr>
    <!--continue the pattern here-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```